# How to capture return value of system command issued in MySQL Client

Tags: mysql, bash, lvm

I'm using a MySQL client connection to issue `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` and then create an LVM snapshot.  I'd like the higher-level script (Ruby) to capture the return code of the snapshot creation, but cannot determine how to capture that within the MySQL client.  To simplify:

```
mysql> system pwd
/root
```

I would expect that `system` to return 0.

```
mysql> system foo
sh: 1: foo: not found
```

I would expect that `system` to return 127 in bash, etc.

Is there some way to retrieve that error code within the MySQL client and return it when the MySQL client exits, write it to a file to read by the controlling script, etc.

Comment: i am not so sure about answer , but tee command in mysql log everthing whatever is on console after login to mysql client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run `FTWRL` in a context where you're also running system commands, *and they depend on each other*, indicates you want to flush, then snapshot, then decide what to do based on that before releasing the table lock.

You'll need to do that in the same script to make sure they work together, and you're trying to do that in the SQL script. It's far easier to do it the other way around, by running the SQL script from *inside* the system script, because you're making decisions based on shell conditions rather than SQL conditions.

Here's how I do that (in Perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DBI;
my $d = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:mysql','root','***');
$d->do('FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK') or die ("Can't flush tables in MySQL");
# Here's the important bit: Capture the status in $s and branch on the result
my $s = system('lvm lvcreate -s -n lv_datadirbackup -L 4G /dev/VG_MYSQL/lv_datadir');
if($s == 0) {
   print ("Snapshot created.\n");
   $d->do('UNLOCK TABLES') or die("Can't unlock tables");
   ... # etc
```

That way you can create the table lock take the snapshot, and use your script to control what happens next based on the snapshot status.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I need to review this one and RandomSeed's to choose, but I will accept once tested out.

Comment: In principal this works, though I'm implementing it in Ruby with the mysql2 gem.  I have noticed that FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK can fail and knock the client off but the command is still executing in MySQL (i.e., it doesn't abort the command gracefully, the script just dies).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
root@localhost> mysql
mysql> system bash
root@localhost> foo
foo: not found
root@localhost> echo $? > logfile
root@localhost> exit
mysql>
```

`logfile` now contains your return value.
If you want to automate it, you could eg. create these scripts:

script_bash.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo
echo $? > logfile
```

script_mysql.sql:

```
system script_bash.sh
```

Then:

```
root@localhost> chmod +x script_bash.sh
root@localhost> mysql < script_mysql.sql #or mysql -e"script_bash.sh"
root@localhost> cat logfile
127
```

Whether you *can* do it does not mean you *should* do it :) I would definitely recommend firing the system command from the "controlling script".

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I need to review this one and Jeremy's to choose, but I will accept once tested out.